# How to change font of all in-text citations in Word 2011?

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, styles, citations

I've got a large .doc file with 20+ citations. I now want to change the font of the in-text citations (so not the bibliography part at the end of the document). How do I do this fast and easy? I cannot seem to find the style that goes with these citation fields.

Answer (score 1):

Set show field codes on: `ALT+F9`

In the search and replace window,

- search for: `^19 CITATION`;
- with advanced options, define your desired formatting.

Click `replace all`.